# Alias template for reference type passed as template template argument in SFINAE context

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae

I encountered the following problem with G++ 6.1.0 (`-std=c++14` switch) and I don't understand why the compiler rejects the code.

I have a helper struct `is_well_formed` which checks if a supplied template template argument is well formed when substituting another supplied type into it:

```cpp
template<template<typename> typename R, typename T, typename = void>
struct is_well_formed : std::false_type {};

template<template<typename> typename R, typename T>
struct is_well_formed<R, T, void_t<R<T>>> : std::true_type {};
```

I want to check whether a type is referenceable. So my idea was to write the following:

```cpp
// (#1)
template<class T>
using reference_t = T&;

static_assert(!is_well_formed<reference_t, void>::value, "Reference to void!?");
```

But I get a compiler error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct is_well_formed<reference_t, double>':
main.cpp:62:51:   required from here
main.cpp:54:20: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<template<class> class R, class T, class> struct is_well_formed'
  : std::false_type {};
                    ^
main.cpp:54:20: note:   expected a class template, got 'reference_t'
main.cpp:54:20: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'is_well_formed<R, T, <template-parameter-1-3> >::is_well_formed'
main.cpp:54:20: note:   expected a class template, got 'reference_t'
```

Alternatively the following works with the same `static_assert`:

```
// (#2)
template<class T>
using reference_t = void_t<T&>;
```

Furthermore the following works, which really puzzles me:

```
// (#3)
template<class T>
using pointer_t = T*;

static_assert(is_well_formed<pointer_t, void>::value, "No pointer to void!?");
```

**What is the difference between the three aliases?** Is the `void_t<T&>` solution the most elegant? Or is it possible to modify the `is_well_formed` helper struct to support the first `reference` version?

**EDIT:** I tested the code with MSVC"15" Preview 4, and `(#1)` and `(#3)` work including the asserts. But when I try `(#2)` the assert for the void reference does not work, i.e. information gets lost during substitution and the `false_type` overload is never selected. Which compiler is right?

The `is_well_formed` helper corresponds to the `can_apply` struct from the which was once documented on Stack Overflow documentation page on [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error), I just removed the parameter packs. Full example code:

```cpp
#include <utility>

// Only defined in std for C++17
template <class...>
using void_t = void;

// (#1) Compiler error during substitution in is_well_formed
template<class T>
using reference_t = T&;

// (#2) Ok, asserts work
/*
template<class T>
using reference_t = void_t<T&>;
*/

// (#3) Ok, asserts work
template<class T>
using pointer_t = T*;

template<template<typename> typename R, typename T, typename = void>
struct is_well_formed 
    : std::false_type {};

template<template<typename> typename R, typename T>
struct is_well_formed<R, T, void_t<R<T>>> 
    : std::true_type {};

int main(int, char**)
{
    static_assert(is_well_formed<reference_t, double>::value, "No reference to double!?");
    static_assert(!is_well_formed<reference_t, void>::value, "Reference to void!?");

    static_assert(is_well_formed<pointer_t, double>::value, "No pointer to double!?");
    static_assert(is_well_formed<pointer_t, void>::value, "No pointer to void!?");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. This only seems to fail if `reference_t` yields a reference type.

Comment: Reported as https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77575

Comment: @T.C. Well, that was fast. :D Really weird if this is actually a bug and nobody encountered/reported it before - this doesn't look like the most exotic code...

Comment: @T.C. Can we close it with an answer that specifies it's a bug, if you don't mind writing one?

Comment: Work also with `decltype(std::declval<T&>())` (which is a correct definition of `reference_t` contrary to `void_t<T&>`).

Comment: For msvc, Did you try with the `make_void` implementation ?

Comment: @Jarod42 @Jarod42 Oh thanks, I didn't think about the reference collapsing rules. I was confused by the `add_rvalue_reference` of `declval`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Do you mean the (#2) test? Yeah it doesn't work in MSVC. Or what do you mean by `make_void`?

Comment: As state in the link, for some compilers/versions, `template <class> using void_t = void;` is not a definition suitable for SFINAE, and require `template <class...>
struct make_void {
    using type = void;
};

template <typename... T>
using void_t = typename make_void<T...>::type;`

Comment: Ah, thanks. When I use the `make_void` version, (#2) works in MSVC. I thought it could handle the shorter version because everything else worked fine.

Comment: Do you consider `decltype(std::declval<T&>())` a workaround or a better solution than simply `T&`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a compiler bug and user [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460120/alias-template-for-reference-type-passed-as-template-template-argument-in-sfinae#comment66241640_39460120) reported it on the GCC Bugzilla [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77575) after seeing this post. User [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460120/alias-template-for-reference-type-passed-as-template-template-argument-in-sfinae#comment66243112_39460120) proposed

```
template<class T>
using reference = decltype(std::declval<T&>());
```

as a working alternative for both MSVC15 and GCC 6.1.0. Furthermore he noted that MSVC still requires the long `void_t` definition

```
template <class...>
struct make_void { using type = void; };

template <typename... T>
using void_t = typename make_void<T...>::type;
```

instead of the obvious

```
template <class...>
using void_t = void;
```

which prevented option `(#2)` in the original post from working.